# systemd ignores drop-in configuration files - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: debian, systemd, cgroups, resources

On one of my machines with Debian Buster (which ships **systemd 241**), I wanted to watch resource usage via `systemd-cgtop`. When I started this utility, I was seeing memory usage, but neither CPU usage nor I/O usage. Obviously, CPU accounting was turned off.

Following the [manpage for system.conf](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html), I put the this line into `/etc/systemd/system.conf` (all other lines already were commented out):

```
DefaultCPUAccounting=yes
```

This worked as expected (of course after having reloaded `systemd` itself by `systemctl daemon-reexec`). [ Note: In fact, I was still seeing CPU usage only for some slices, not for all, but this is another story / question. ]

However, that man page does not recommend to change `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. Rather, we should create a drop-in configuration file with the required lines. I followed that advice, created the directory `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d`, and created a file `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/10-pp.conf`. Then I removed the line shown above from `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, put it into `/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/10-pp.conf`, and issued `systemctl daemon-reexec`.

This took me back to the beginning: `systemd-cgtop` didn't show CPU usage at all.

I can reproduce the situation at any time. Regardless of the drop-in configuration file, I must alter the main configuration file to enable CPU accounting.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S.

- I have verified that there is no other drop-in configuration file which could hurt mine. That is, `/usr/lib/systemd/system.conf.d/` does not exist, nor does  `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system.conf.d/`, nor does `/run/systemd/system.conf.d/`.
- I have verified the access permissions of the directory and the file I have created. They are like the permissions of the other (installed-by-default) `.d` directories and the files in them, respectively.

Answer (score 5):

I was unsure whether I should delete the question because the problem was due to my own fault. However, for everybody who is about to make the same newbie mistake:

In the drop-in configuration file, I had forgotten to put the line

```
[Manager]
```

at the beginning. That's all - silly me. I really should have remembered that *every* configuration relating to systemd must be in the appropriate section; it is the same as in e.g. service units.